# I have done slicing with photoshop set the back ground in HTML and want to enter some text on the slice for text how do I do that?

Tags: html, photoshop

I have sliced an image making an HTML file with tables. I centered it with  tag and then I put the background image which repeats which I want it to repeat. and now I want to put some text on the field which I had specified for putting text.( I want to put text on an image which is there in table format) I don't know how to put text on that text field(table)with image. Please answer in detail as much as possible as I am new to the technology.

Thanks for reading and replying.

Comment: Could you give us a clue as to the html you're working with? (View Source in the browser, then paste a demonstrative snippet of the code.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to have your text be embedded in the image or keep it as html text that can be selected and spidered?

If it's the latter, I've always exported my sliced up image and html then opened it up in dreamweaver.  I then go to the section I want text to appear and I set the image occupying the space as the background image for that table cell (`<td background="/path/to/myslice_1.jpg">some text</td>`).  You can then put whatever you like inside the cell such as text.  You just have to keep in mind the size and amount of text you want to fill the space as your slicing up the image, because anything that takes up more space than you've allowed will break your slices apart.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some STYLE to your table cell(s), because html works with css just fine.
AsWuLongTi mentioned above, you can write:

```
<td>text</td>
```

and then use css option 'style' on it:

```
<td style ="background: red;">text</td>
```

then in place of 'red' set path to your image:

```
<td style="background-image: url("/path/to/myslice.jpg");">text</td>
```